# Catching stdout from win32com?

Tags: python, com, lotus-notes

I am trying to run some tasks over lotus notes, but when coming accroess a entry with a bad password it is stopping me dead in my tracks.  I have searched around the forum for clue and have read up on `subprocess` but haven't been able to get it to work for my case?  How could I do this?

```
        try:
            print "session"+str(count)
            print count
            print task
            print "session["+str(count-1)+"].Initialize()"
            session[count-1].Initialize()
            reg = session[count-1].createRegistration()
            reg.switchToID(os.path.join(IDPATH,task[1]),task[2])

        except Exception as inst:
            print type(inst)
            print inst.args
            if type(inst) == TypeError:

                x, y ,u , i = inst.args
                #print 'x = ', x
                #print 'y = ', y
                #print 'u = ', u
                #print 'i = ', i
                logfile.write(task[0]+"\t"+task[1]+"\t"+task[2]+"\tNA\t"+u[2]+"\n")
                continue
```

Id the password for the id file matches out, everything works great, once I hit one with a bad password I get.

has password

```
session[1].Initialize()
[0734:0007-2CF0] The ID file being used is: CN=Test User1/O=company
[0734:0007-2CF0] Enter password (press the Esc key to abort):
```

I was hoping I could find a way to parse on this error and send a esc to move on to the next.

Comment: does the exception fire? or not? if you add a print statement right after reg.switchToID do you see the printstatement before it tells you that your password was wrong or whatever?

Comment: Exception does not appear to be catching, added a print after the switchToID, does not print.  Prompted to enter a correct password for that ID file and stays.

Answer (score 1):

Lotus Notes does not normally allow a calling program to interecept this password prompt. That's a security countermeasure against scripts that are attempting brute force attacks. The only way I know of to get around this is to use the [Lotus Notes C API](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/documentation/capi/)'s Extension Manager feature, which involves building a DLL to handle EM_GETPASSWORD events, and inserting an entry into the notes.ini file so that Notes will load this DLL when it runs.

Comment: Ah, that would make since.  I was hoping I could maybe wrap it in a subprocess and close it after a timeout period with no 0 return and move on to the next to test. Wishful thinking I guess.